# regex to find a substring with key value pair

Tags: regex

I want a regex for below scenario:

Input String: 
"/eve/?tr=abcd&ay=123&test=123456789&e=event"

Output of regex should be (Search for attribute "test" and get the value against it: 123456789

I am using regex: [/test=([^\"]*)/, 1] but it returns string "123456789&e=event"

How to correct this regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match everything up to the next `&`, not `"`:

```
[/test=([^&]*)/, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Regexes aren't a magic wand that you wave at every programming problem that involves strings.

What language are you doing this in?  Try to use existing tools instead of parsing your own with regexes.  If you're using PHP, for example, use the [parse_url](http://ca.php.net/parse_url) function and then use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to break apart the query string on `=` and `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex !
You can extract anything before & .

```
&test=([^&]*)
```

I am also attach the output of the regex , you can verify it .

[image]